# Dividir datos de diferentes tablas en sql

Tags: sql

estoy haciendo una consulta sql para sacar promedios de accesos para lo cual primero hago una consulta para extraer todos los accesos de una tabla y dividirlos para otro campo de una tabla diferente.

La primera tabla se llama TrackEvent y de ella extraigo una columna la cual la

he divido para un numero para poder obtner un promedio teniendo la siguiente consulta:

```
select count(event)/74 from ABC.TrackEvent where course_display_name = "course-v1-AGROSYS-Ed2-2017-FEB" and session !="";
```

la otra tabla que tengo se llama estudiantes y cuenta unicamente con dos columnas la primera es el nombre del curso y la siguiente el numero de estudiantes.
es decir:
Tabla estudiantes

curso:course-v1-AGROSYS-Ed2-2017-FEB

numero_estudiantes: 74

Como puedo hacer para reemplazar el numero 74 de la consulta antes mostrada por el valor de la columna numero_estudiantes de la tabla estudiantes.

gracias

Comment: Y la tabla estudiantes solo cuenta con un solo registro? o quieres sustituirlo por cada registro que haya en la tabla de estudiantes?

Comment: no la tabla estudiantes cuenta con 25 registros de 25 cursos, los cuales son identificados en la tabla TrackEvent con la columna course_display_name y en la tabla estudiantes los cursos estan dientificados con la columna curso, si ue el numero se sustituya ee acuerdo al numero de estudiantes que tenga en la tabla estudiantes

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(event)/(SELECT numero_estudiantes  FROM  Tabla_estudiantes WHERE course_display_name = "course-v1-AGROSYS-Ed2-2017-FEB" ) from ABC.TrackEvent where course_display_name = "course-v1-AGROSYS-Ed2-2017-FEB" and session !="";`     Me parece que con una sub consulta se va

Comment: Creo que tienes que ser más específico, que obtienes en la primera consulta y con ese resultado que deseas hacer. Luis fernando, dado que dice que en su tabla hay 25 registros, una subconsulta así marcará error por no tener un único valor devuelto )

Comment: @LuisFernando gracias hombre funciono perfecto

Comment: No importa que tenga 25 registros ya que solo iras a traer el numero de estudiantes de un curso especifico, entonces solo devolvera un numero.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(event)/(SELECT numero_estudiantes FROM Tabla_estudiantes WHERE course_display_name = "course-v1-AGROSYS-Ed2-2017-FEB" ) from ABC.TrackEvent where course_display_name = "course-v1-AGROSYS-Ed2-2017-FEB" and session !="";
```

Me parece que con una subconsulta se va